# Excec, List data With values

Tags: excel, sorting, dynamic

In a Excelsheet: In column AL I have the names of the employees (1 961). I have their wages in Column AM.
I want to sort this dynamically in an another column P from the highest wage to the lowest. The data comes from another woorkbook and changes sometimes so the list have to be dynamically sorted.

In Column AR I have this formula to rank the wages:

```
=Count.IF(AM$2:AM$1961">="&AM2)
```

Then in Column P I have this formula to display the sorted list with names (AL).

```
=INDEX($AL$2:$AL$1961;MATCH(ROWS($AR$2:$AR2);$AR$2:$AR$1961;0))
```

The sorted list works fine except when I have two persons with the same wage. If so, the list display the first persons name and leave the the others with NA. Is there a way to display the list with all persons?

Comment: `=Count.IF(...`  I'm not aware of that syntax.  What version of Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about that `=COUNT.If(...` function as I've not seen it in Excel for Windows.  But a formula to determine unique rank, where there might be duplicates, would be:

```
 AR2: =RANK(AM2,$AM$2:$AM$1961,0 )+COUNTIF($AM$2:AM2,AM2)-1
```

and fill down to AR1961

You should then be able to use the `INDEX/MATCH` form to return the correct name.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I will test it on monday back at work. I meant countif not count.if.

Comment: @ThomasH Glad to help.  Could you please accept it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark?